# Scroll within an iFrame on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, click, anchor

I have a job application form being pulled into another page using an iFrame. If the user hits submit and there are errors on the page, an overlay box appears (much like a lightbox) that gives a validation error message to the user. It has an 'okay' button that then closes the window.

I would like for the click of the button to bring the user back to the top of the page, since the iFrame has a height of about 1000px. Again, this is all happening within the iFrame. The pop up in the iFrame will bring you to an anchor at the top of the iFrame. No cross-domain craziness going on here.

I would prefer to do this with jquery, as I already have a click function associated with the button, but if I absolutely have to use old-timey Javascript DOM methods, I'll settle.

I've tried scrollTo, animate, appending an anchor to the iFrame's src, and nothing has worked. I also haven't been getting any errors to guide me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

```
if(errors > 0) {
    var header = "It appears there was a problem!";
    var message = "There are <b><u>"+errors+"</u></b> errors with your application.<br/><br/>";
        message += "<b>Please re-attach your resume once you have corrected the errors.</b>";

    jQuery("#infoMessage .infoText").html("<h2>"+header+"</h2><p>"+message+"</p>");
    jQuery("#infoMessage button").button();

    jQuery("button.okButton").click(function() {
        jQuery("#infoMessage").fadeOut();
        jQuery(".light_overlay").fadeOut();
        return false;

        //alert('testing');
        // Do not use .scrollTop() as it is deprecated.
        jQuery('body').prop('scrollTop', 0);
        // Additionaly, animate it.
        jQuery('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });

    });

    jQuery("#infoMessage").fadeIn('slow');
    jQuery(".light_overlay").fadeIn();

}
```

This is the last snippet of code I was suggested to add and it did not work (4 lines after the commented out alert)

Comment: Questions without code and error messages are much harder to answer

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you are using jQuery, there are still things to keep in mind, much less than traditional JavaScript though.

1. Use 'body' instead of document when scrolling.
2. Use prop() to set scrollTop
3. Always call event.preventDefault() if you are handling click events on anchors.

Sample code:

```
// Do not use .scrollTop() as it is deprecated.
$('body').prop('scrollTop', 0);

// Additionaly, animate it.
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not do the trick either. Nothing is happening and there are no errors on the page.

Just to give some background, I have an errorMessagingCheck function, declaring an errors variable and counting how many errors there are on the page. I'll paste the code in the above question as an update

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<iframe>` with a `<div>` and use absolute position as well as set it's top and left to 0. This will allow you to move the `iframe` where you want it as well as allowing you to set the scroll position programmatically.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BDC9Q/35/

Comment: The button that's being clicked, as I mentioned, is within the iFrame - but in a overlay box, not on the page itself.

Comment: So I gave an id of wrap to my surrounding div, and included -- jQuery('#wrap').prop('scrollTop', 0); -- I'm a little confused about the first use of -- $wrap.prop('scrollTop', 500); -- you said to simulate scrolling? What is this doing?

Comment: I just did that to simulate the page already being scrolled down some and showing that it scrolls back up after clicking the button